# Vaadin with Grails Database error

Tags: java, grails, vaadin

I am using `vaadin7` with `grails` i have created model and service and trying to access it when click on `login` button to check `login` details.

I search a lot but no relevant result, i am new to grails framework.

i am getting below error when trying to access service class:-

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.support.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:85)
    at com.xfuel.web.services.PeopleService.checkLogin(PeopleService.groovy)
    at com.xfuel.web.services.PeopleService$checkLogin.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at test.Test$2.buttonClick(Test.groovy:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:984)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:393)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

My `Vaadin`code is below :-

```
class Test  extends UI {

    public Test() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {

        HorizontalLayout fields = new HorizontalLayout();
        fields.setSpacing(true);
        fields.setMargin(true);
        fields.addStyleName("fields");

        final TextField username = new TextField("Username");
        username.focus();
        fields.addComponent(username);

        final PasswordField password = new PasswordField("Password");
        fields.addComponent(password);

        final Button signin = new Button("Sign In");
        signin.addStyleName("default");
        fields.addComponent(signin);
        fields.setComponentAlignment(signin, Alignment.BOTTOM_LEFT);

        final ShortcutListener enter = new ShortcutListener("Sign In",
                KeyCode.ENTER, null) {
            @Override
            public void handleAction(Object sender, Object target) {
                signin.click();
            }
        };

        signin.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                if (username.getValue() != null
                        && username.getValue().equals("")
                        && password.getValue() != null
                        && password.getValue().equals("")) {
                    signin.removeShortcutListener(enter);
                    PeopleService p1 = new PeopleService();
                    p1.checkLogin("", "");
                 //   iPeopleService.checkLogin(username.getValue(), password.getValue());
                    buildMainView();
                } else {

                }
            }
        });

        signin.addShortcutListener(enter);
        setContent(fields);
    }
}
```

And domain class :-

```
class People {

    String name;
    String apppassword;

    static constraints = {

    }
}
```

and `Grails` services code :-

```
@Transactional
class PeopleService {
  def serviceMethod() {

    }


    public People checkLogin(String username, String password) {
        def query = People.where{
             peopleID == username &&
             apppassword == password &&
             visible == true
         }
         return people = query.find()

    }
```

i below is the `datasource` :-

```
development {
        dataSource {
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/sample"
              username = "root"
              password = "root"
              loggingSql = true
        }
    }
```

i did not understand the reason of this error. Can someone please help me?

Thanks

Comment: is your grails service in `grails-app/services`?  can you try `PeopleService p1 = Grails.get(PeopleService)` instead?

Comment: Let me try it. 
yes i am using `grails-app/services/` can i call it directly from `Java` class with some return type? (I meant i want service to return some bean to my calling `Java` class so that i can use it)

Comment: in java it would look like `Grails.get(PeopleService.class)`.  You can also call the method directly `Grails.get(PeopleService).doSomething()`.  Why are you using java, when you have groovy with grails?

Comment: Because i have download `vaadin` sample application which is in `java` and i tried to convert all `java` file extension to `groovy` i got number of error because of button `listener` and some other unknowen error while run the application. So i thought to use service and model in `grooy` and `ui` component in `java`. Am i doing somthing wrong?

Comment: you are free to use java and groovy well side by side.  i only was curious.  have you tried accessing the service in a "spring"-y way yet and does that fix your problem?

Comment: Yes i have added service bean in `spring dsl` but when i debug the application  i got  service bean null so i used new operator.

Comment: if it's in grails-app/services you don't need to wire it up manually.  have you tried Grails.get()?  which is needed to access the spring context and the services.